# Running PowerShell from Java loading 3rd party Modules - ResourceUnavailable: FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, powershell, powershell-module

I'm porting over a PS4 script that is leveraging a 3rd party modules (NetCmdlets) and works perfectly fine from the Powershell window, but seems to have lost track of how to load 3rd party modules when run from a Java Program.

I'd be interested in anyone's thoughts as to a potential cause and solution to this...

Here is the Calling Java PGM:

```
package ImagineOne.PSJava2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ExecuteCommand {

 /**
  * @param args
  * @throws IOException 
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  // This is the command
 //  String command = "powershell.exe  $PSVersionTable.PSVersion | Get-Member";
 // String command = "powershell.exe  C:\\Users\\versaggi\\Desktop\\PowerCLI\\DevScripts\\CANES_VMWare_Extraction_Functions.ps1";
 String command = "powershell.exe  C:\\Users\\versaggi\\Desktop\\PowerCLI\\DevScripts\\CANES_IBM_RackSwitch_Extraction_Functions.ps1";

  Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
  powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
  String line;

  System.out.println("Output:");
  BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));

  while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
  }

  stdout.close();
  System.out.println("Error:");
  BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getErrorStream()));

  while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
  }

  stderr.close();
  System.out.println("Done");

 }

} //End Class
```

This is the OUTPUT:

```
Output:
** NetCmdlets Modules Loaded ** 
** Disconnected from RackSwitch ** 
Error:
Import-Module : **The specified module 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.
0\Modules\NetCmdlets\NetCmdlets.psd1' was not loaded because no valid module 
file was found in any module directory**.At C:\Users\versaggi\Desktop\PowerCLI\De
vScripts\CANES_IBM_RackSwitch_Extraction_Functions.ps1:732 char:1
+ Import-Module 
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\NetCmdlets\NetC ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\Windows\Syst...NetCmdle 
   ts.psd1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm 
   ands.ImportModuleCommand

Done
```

This is the PowerShell Script: (which is only supposed to load the modules as a test [proof of concept])

```
Import-Module C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\NetCmdlets\NetCmdlets.psd1

write-host "** NetCmdlets Modules Loaded ** "
```

Some R&D I've perused to consider:

http://technirman.blogspot.com/2014/06/invoke-powershell-commands-through-java.html

https://blogs.oracle.com/vaibhav/entry/not_as_easy_as_we

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d32537bd-0aef-440e-8760-6b3085390c37/executing-powershell-script-via-java?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: I have fixed the Java/Powershell interoperability issue just now. On a hunch (after some digging into what VMware did w/their modules which never had problem) I surmised that the NetCmdlets had installed their modules in a protected space (see dir below) in the Windows OS by default. After moving to an unprotected user space (See dir Below)  it worked just fine. I even did a bit of stress testing and it stood up well.

Protected Win OS Space:

$PSHome\Modules (%Windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules) 

Unprotected Space:
C:\Users\versaggi\Desktop\PowerCLI\windowspowershell\modules

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the Java/Powershell interoperability issue just now. On a hunch (after some digging into what **VMware** did w/their modules which never had problem) I surmised that the **NetCmdlets** had installed their modules in a ***protected space*** (see dir below) in the Windows OS by default. After moving to an ***unprotected user space*** (See dir Below)  it worked just fine. I even did some stress testing and it stood up well.

Protected Win OS Space:

```
$PSHome\Modules (%Windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules)
```

Unprotected Space:

```
C:\Users\versaggi\Desktop\PowerCLI\windowspowershell\modules
```

Per the Windows Docs on the Subject:

**Install Modules in PSModulePath**

Whenever possible, install all modules in a path that is listed in the PSModulePath environment variable or add the module path to the PSModulePath environment variable value.
The PSModulePath environment variable ($env:PSModulePath) contains the locations of Windows PowerShell modules. ***Cmdlets rely on the value of this environment variable to find modules.***

By default, the PSModulePath environment variable value contains the following system and user module directories, but you can add to and edit the value.

***$PSHome\Modules (%Windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules)***

**Warning Caution:**

This location is reserved for modules that ship with Windows. **Do not install modules to this location.**